# How can one do a query in Oracle 10g on more than one table?

Tags: oracle

I am working on a project using oracle APEX.  How can one do a query in Oracle 10g on more than one table? I'd appreciate a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 3):

Ambrose,

Is your question about SQL in general? If so, You can query data from more than one table using Joins.

Please look at an introduction to joins here.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046

If it is related to Oracle Apex tool where you are trying to display data from more than one table in a report, then identify and locate the  query that is used as the Source in the report.

You'll need to modify the existing query there to include the new table , add the necessary columns in the select list and joins at the end of the query to get the data displayed from both the tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apex's builtin Query Builder to get you started. It will generate the query for you and you will probably be able to pick it up by examining what it generates and learning from it.

However, keep in mind that SQL syntax is usually taught in university-level courses, so don't expect to be able to build complex queries without undertaking some education of some kind. Rajesh's link to the Oracle docs is a good start.